# .NET Swagger UI Primary API Specification

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, swagger-ui

How to configure primary name in .NET Swagger UI? I want to specify, which API specification Swagger UI shows when launched. I'm using .NET Core 3.1.

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    var swaggerJsonBasePath = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.RoutePrefix) ? "." : "..";
    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{swaggerJsonBasePath}/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API v1");
    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{swaggerJsonBasePath}/swagger/v2/swagger.json", "API v2");
    // How to configure urls.primaryName = "API v2"?
    // Now "API v1" is shown by default and I'd like to show "API v2" instead.
});
```

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60186760/how-can-i-specify-the-default-opening-version-of-swagger

Comment: It does but didn't provide an actual solution. However, it did point me to a real solution: the launchSettings.json should have:
`"launchUrl": "swagger/index.html?urls.primaryName=API%20v2",`